# How do I insert multiple buttons with bound events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a factory that creates buttons,

```
var btnFactory = (fn, text) => {
    var btn = $(`<button>${text}</button>`);
    btn.bind("click", fn);
    return btn;
};
```

I want to be able insert multiple buttons, events already bound to handlers, into an element so I end up with,

```
<div>
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out to use `.html()` for it, but so far it's eluded me.

Comment: Is your issue that the buttons are not working, or not being inserted properly, or..?

Comment: I don't see an actual question there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery (and it's more efficient)

```
// reusable template element for cloning
const btnTemplate = (() => {
  const bt = document.createElement("button")
  bt.type = "button"
  // other things you want all buttons to have, classname, etc.
  return bt
})()

const btnFactory = { fn, text } => {
  const btn = btnTemplate.cloneNode(false)
  btn.onclick = fn
  btn.innerHTML = text
  return btn
}
```

Can be used like

```
const items = [ 
  { text: "Button1", fn: e => console.log("Button1 clicked") },
  { text: "Button2", fn: e => console.log("Button2 clicked") }
]

// Higher-order helper to fold a collection and a factory into
// a documentFragment
const intoDocFrag = (factoryFn, xs) =>
  xs.reduce((frag, x) => { 
    frag.appendChild(factoryFn(x))
    return frag
  }, document.createDocumentFragment())


document.body.appendChild(intoDocFrag(btnFactory, items))
```

Comment: OP mentioned he was trying to use .html(), I answered with how to use .html() but am a huge fan of your answer. No need for jQuery here.

Comment: Weird...I actually deleted this question as I figured it out. Guess SO had other ideas. Enjoy your points!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is how to use this function to generate the button? I put a couple different ways to do that in the snippet below:

```js
var btnFactory = (fn, text) => {
    var btn = $(`<button>${text}</button>`);
    btn.bind("click", fn);
    return btn;
};

// method 1
$('body').html(
    btnFactory(
        (function () {
            console.log('test 1')
        }),
        'test 1'
    )
)

// method 2
$('body').append(
  btnFactory(
    (function () {
      console.log('test 2');
    }),
    'test 2'
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean inserting a series of buttons with a for loop, then it's quite simple. You need to give the `div` element an ID, and create an variable like so: `var divElement = document.getElementById('divElement1');`. Then you create a for loop, and insert the amount of buttons like so:

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment()
for (var i = 1; i < (amount of buttons you want); i++)
{
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", fn);
button.value = "Button" + i;
docFrag.appendChild(button);
}
divElement.appendChild(docFrag);
```

Hope this helps!